# animateOnLayoutChanges outside parent?

Tags: android, animation

```
<LinearLayout android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

    <LinearLayout android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >
            <TextView />
            <TextView />
            <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >
            <EditText />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to hide the middle TextView from the upper child, and the EditText just jumps to place instead of using any animation.

When I use **setVisibility(View.GONE);** on any of these LinearLayouts children I get an animation for this, but I want to use the animation to animate the second layout aswell.

Using ObjectAnimator

```
    animation_01 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( view, "translationY", 0, -200 );
```

works like it should on the animation part, but it leaves an empty area under it. Any kind of animation programatically started seem to mess things up so I want to use the one thats working pretty well on its own.

Using the children in the same parent is not possible, because it has different backgroundcolors etc (The top part is a header, which has different objects you can hide and show again with a button, setting the visibility).

I want the first children to use its animation to the second child but when I choose to hide any objects from the top one, the other follow, but it has no animation.

Is this possible?

**Solution.. for now!**

This worked.. part of it anyway. I might aswell use a LinearLayout because all I did was to set background color to the individual objects instead of its parent.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:animateLayoutChanges="true" > <!-- blue bg -->
        <TextView /> 
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <EditText /> <!-- white bg -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```